# Using Export to save output of Show as an svg file makes disorders text in the files

Tags: export, svg-format

I used the code shown below to save the output of `Show`:

```
tr = -2;
ro = 2;
v = 2;
f[x_, y_] := -ro v x - (y + tr ro)^2
ss = ContourPlot[f[x, y] == 0, {x, -16, 0}, {y, -6, 0}];
dtd = RegionPlot[
   ro tr + Sqrt[ro v x + (ro tr^2)] > 0, {x, 0, 7}, {y, -5, 5}, 
   PlotStyle -> Pink];
topp = Plot[{0}, {x, -20, 5}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Filling -> 5, 
   FillingStyle -> {Directive[Opacity[0.2], Green]}, 
   GridLines -> {None, {0.5}}];
dd = RegionPlot[-ro v x - (y + tr ro)^2 > 0 && y - ro tr > 0, {x, -20,
     0}, {y, -5, 0}, PlotStyle -> Purple];
pol1 = Graphics[
   Text[Style["\!\(\* Polarized\)", Large, Bold, White, 
     FontFamily -> "Times"], {-2.8, -0.2}]];
yax = Line[{{0, -5}, {0, 5}}];
a4 = Plot[{v x/(-4 tr), 0}, {x, -16, 0}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.006], {Blue, Dashing[None]}}, 
   Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, {Orange, Yellow}}}];
yaxx = Graphics[{Thick, Black, yax}];
xax = Line[{{-20, 0}, {7, 0}}];
xaxx = Graphics[{Thick, Black, xax}];
Show[ss, a4, dd, topp, dtd, pol1, xaxx, yaxx, PlotRange -> All, 
 Axes -> True, 
 AxesLabel -> {Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], r], \[CapitalLambda]}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Large, Black]]
```

When I evaluate the `Show` expression at top-level, I can drag the edge of the figure to enlarge it and make written items in the figure move to an appropriate place. But when I use `Export`, I don't have the chance to make output into the appropriate size after I save it. What should I do? In above figure, here should be written in orange region.

Comment: I think this is likely to a magnification issue, but since you don't supply the definitions of variables, I can't actually experiment with your figure and verify my guess. Please provide definitions for your variables. Try to reduce their number to a few as necessary to recreate the problem.

Comment: I add definitions. "here" should be printed in orange region @m_goldberg

Comment: No time for a full answer, but you can add `ImageSize -> 1000` to the options of `Show`. Seems to work fine on my machine.

Comment: If you want to resize your image by hand, do so and then add `Export["filename.svg", <resized image in here> ]` around your resized image. Although it might be cleaner to get the actual output you want from `Show`.